# How to understand torch.arange(0, 3).view(-1, *[1]*3)

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

In Pytorch, for the code:

```
torch.arange(0, 3).view(-1, *[1]*3)
```

The result is:

```
tensor([[[[0]]],


    [[[1]]],


    [[[2]]]])


    torch.Size([3, 1, 1, 1])
```

Where [1] * 3 = [1, 1, 1], but I don`t understand the * before [1] * 3. What is the meaning of it? Thanks.

Comment: The second answer on the question Michael Szczesny posted directly addresses your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36926/2790047

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While links provided in the comments describe parts of the solution, whole thing might be missing, hence, let’s disentangle this `view` method:

```
.view(-1,...)
```

Means “all the elements”, in your case it is 3 as you have `[0, 1, 2]` with length of 3.

Next:

```
[1] * 3
```

Is a Python trick to create new list with single element repeated multiple times.

It is the same as

```
[1, 1, 1]
```

Now unpacking with asterisk “unpacks” values as arguments to function, in this case:

```
.view(-1, [1, 1, 1])
```

Becomes:

```
.view(-1, 1, 1, 1)
```

And the whole thing is (according to first step):

```
.view(3, 1, 1, 1)
```

BTW. Please don't do that under most circumstances, it’s pretty hard to follow as one can see above.

Comment: Thanks, now I got it.